# How to use springframework AssertFileEquals?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I am trying to compare 2 files and see if they are the same with the spring framework.

The documentation on the assertFileEquals function says to use it like this:

```
private static final String EXPECTED_FILE = "src/main/resources/data/input.txt";
private static final String OUTPUT_FILE = "target/test-outputs/output.txt";

AssertFile.assertFileEquals(new FileSystemResource(EXPECTED_FILE), 
                        new FileSystemResource(OUTPUT_FILE));
```

Doing this, eclipse says 'Unhandled exception type Exception'
When adding catch I get the following error after running:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/Assert
at org.springframework.batch.test.AssertFile.assertFileEquals(AssertFile.java:42)
at org.springframework.batch.test.AssertFile.assertFileEquals(AssertFile.java:56)
at Main.main(Main.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.Assert
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 3 more
```

Can anyone explain how this is solved or how I use this function?
I have also tried giving it two equal files, but still this persists.

Comment: could you check if you have `junit-addons-1.4.jar` in your classpath

Comment: You're missing a library or dependency on your test classpath, like the error says.

Comment: Thanks guys I'll check that and get back to you.

Comment: junit-addons-1.4.jar is in eclipse under reference libraries in Package explorer. It is also in the Java Build path in eclipse under Libraries and under Order and Export.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the advice of Ashish and Dave Newton I looked for a jar containing junit/framework/Assert and found junit-4.4. Added this as a referenced library and it's fixed. Seems that the spring framework uses this.

Thanks for your help guys.